# Cant save Word macro because the file is read only

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have the following problem. I try to save one Macro under the normal.dotm in Word. I open word > go to developer > go under macros > create > copy paste the macro as a Normal Module and click save. Upon clicking save I get the error message "This file is read only". Then it gives me the option to create an alternative normal.dotm, but if I want to overwrite my initial normal.dotm it says that it is already in use and that I cant do that.

Edit: The only ideas I have right now is that normal.dotm opens as read only for whatever reason. If so how do I detect that and how do I change that?

Any idea what is going on and what I could do to resolve this?

Comment: [Change the Normal template Normal.dotm](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-Normal-template-Normal-dotm-06de294b-d216-47f6-ab77-ccb5166f98ea#ID0EAABAAA=2016,_2013,_2010)

Comment: (didn't notice there was a link, just a second)

Comment: It's a link to Office documentation, click it! ;)

Comment: I read the contents under the link, but I still don't see what (exactly) I have to do. Do you mean to just make any change to it or to modify it not to be read only (at this point I have already looked at normal.dotm (right click --> properties) and I see that the box "read only" is not ticked as such I cant imagine it is that. Unless I am missing something and one needs to change some property within the document not to be read only). At this point what I will test is to delete my normal.dotm and see if the word recreates a non read only version.

Comment: Do you open the Normal.dotm directly or not? Because if you open another document or just word, Normal will be locked for sure.

Comment: Do you even open it directly in this case? Whether normal.dotm is read only is determined in its properties which are accessed through right clicking the document. Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point is to open directly the file `Normal.dotm`, because it's the only way it isn't locked.

---

For Word 2010, 2013 and 2016 (from [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-Normal-template-Normal-dotm-06de294b-d216-47f6-ab77-ccb5166f98ea#ID0EAABAAA=2016,_2013,_2010)) :

1. Go to `C:\Users\<YOUR USER NAME>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`
2. Open the Normal template (**Normal.dotm**)
3. **Make any changes** that you want to the fonts, margins, spacing, and other settings. You can use the same commands and features that you use to change a document — but **remember that any changes that you make to Normal.dotm will be applied to documents that you create in the future**.
4. **When** you have **finished**, click the **File tab**, and then click **Save**

Comment: So what change do I have to make in order to make it not read only (sorry if I misunderstood your answerer as to what I have to do).

Comment: @Noir : Did you close all Words before **opening directly the `Normal.dotm`**?

Comment: Even if I did so it did not work, as I was informed that another application is using it (although there should not have been any). As such I had to start the computer in safe mode.

Comment: @Noir : You could have check in the list of running apps (with Ctrl+Alt+Del) if there was a WINWORD.EXE left, or use [Unlocker](https://unlocker.fr.softonic.com/). Did you manage to make it work?